# How to set sessionStorage before UIWebView loads request?

Tags: javascript, swift, uiwebview, sessionstorage

**Code**

Here is what I've been trying to do:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/index.html")
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "sessionStorage.setItem('exampleKey','exampleValue');")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

**Problem**

However, when looking the console in Safari for the Simulator sessionStorage does not contain `exampleKey`.

**Question**

How can I set the sessionStorage before loading `http://example.com/index.html`?

**Edit**

Solution proposed by Alexandre Lara does not work for me.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/index.html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "sessionStorage.setItem('exampleKey','exampleValue');")
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by implementing `webView(_:shouldStartLoadWith:navigationType:)` from `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
class WebViewViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    // ...
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/index.html")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    // ...

    // Set delegate and implement the method
    webView.delegate = self

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) {
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "sessionStorage.setItem('exampleKey','exampleValue');")
    }
}
```